# Convert NSDictionary string to NSDictionary

Tags: nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

How do i convert an NSString to a NSDictionary Object? Or 
initialize an NSDictionary from an NSString?

Here is an NSString to be converted. Inside this dictionary example, there is an array inserted:

```
{

("My value.")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use JSON strings that can be easily converted (via NSData) from and to NSArrays and NSDictionarys.

See NSJSONSerialization: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your object should be in key value format like this...

```
{
    "myData":("My value.")
}
```